# Regex to find dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, replaceall, replace

I have a pretty simple code and in one case it works, and not in all the case, I wanted to know what I'm missing
I'm trying to match a date in this format dd/mm/yyyy

This is my code:

```
String d = '20/03/2020';
System.debug(Pattern.matches('(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([0-9]{4})', d)); // returns false
d.replace('(0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/([0-9]{4})', 'test');
System.debug(d); //returns D inchanged : 20/03/2020 and not 'test'
```

I also tried to simply the regex and there the Pattern function works...

```
String d = '20/03/2020';
System.debug(Pattern.matches('[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', d)); // returns true
d.replace('([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})', 'test');
System.debug(d); //returns d inchanged : 20/03/2020 and not 'test'
```

I've tried many many many solution and regexs and I  can't figure out why in a particular case it seems to works

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. [`replace(String target, String replacement)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace) doesn't take a regExp as input, but a literal string.
   You should have used [`replaceAll(String regExp, String replacement)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll)
2. Strings are immutable, so doing `d.replace()` or `d.replaceAll()` will not change that instance. Indeed they return a new string, so you should assign it to `d`.

Therefore the code should look like:

```java
String d = '20/03/2020';
System.debug(Pattern.matches('[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', d)); // true
d = d.replaceAll('[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}', 'test');
System.debug(d); // test
```